# Convert List of Bytes to integer value in Flutter

Tags: flutter, parsing, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I am having trouble removing brackets from the value that I am getting from ESP32 i.e BLE device. I want to show the value without brackets in the Heart Rate Widget, but I am difficulty resolving that. Kindly help me out in finding its solution. The data that is coming from device is converted to String format

BLE code:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key key, this.device}) : super(key: key);
  final BluetoothDevice device;
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  // BLE
  final String SERVICE_UUID = "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b";
  final String CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8";
  bool isReady;
  Stream<List<int>> stream;
  List<int> lastValue;
  List<double> traceDust = List();

  connectToDevice() async {

    // await widget.device.connect();
    print("connected");
    discoverServices();
  }

  discoverServices() async {

    List<BluetoothService> services = await widget.device.discoverServices();
    services.forEach((service) {
      if (service.uuid.toString() == SERVICE_UUID) {
        service.characteristics.forEach((characteristic) {
          if (characteristic.uuid.toString() == CHARACTERISTIC_UUID) {
            characteristic.setNotifyValue(!characteristic.isNotifying);
            stream = characteristic.value;
            print(stream);
            lastValue = characteristic.lastValue;
            print(lastValue);

            setState(() {
              isReady = true;
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Heart Rate Widget Code:

```
Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              //width: double.infinity,
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
                                    stream: stream,
                                    initialData: lastValue,
                                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                                        AsyncSnapshot<List<int>> snapshot) {
                                      if (snapshot.hasError)
                                        return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
                                            fontSize: 19,
                                            color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                            height: 1.4736842105263157,
                                          ),
                                        );

                                      if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                          ConnectionState.active) {
                                        var currentValue = snapshot.data.toString();
                                        //traceDust.add(double.tryParse(currentValue) ?? 0);
                                        return Text('$currentValue',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
                                            fontSize: 19,
                                            color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                            height: 1.4736842105263157,
                                          ),
                                          );
                                      } else {
                                        return Text('Check the stream',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
                                            fontSize: 19,
                                            color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                            height: 1.4736842105263157,
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 5,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Heart Rate',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
                                      fontSize: 19,
                                      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                      height: 1.2777777777777777,
                                    ),
                                    textHeightBehavior: TextHeightBehavior(
                                        applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
```

I am getting Values like this (as shown above Heart Rate):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what value are you expecting in your question. I'll assume it is `33` although that seems very low for a heart rate reading.

I would expect the data is a list of Bytes so you will need to convert that into an integer value.

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() {
  var value =  Uint8List.fromList([33]);
  print("stream.value: ${value}"); // stream.value: [33]
  var hr = ByteData.sublistView(value, 0, 1);
  print("Heart rate: ${hr.getUint8(0)}"); // Heart rate: 33
}
```

It appears the BLE device isn't following the Bluetooth standard for how to send Heart Rate Measurements as detailed in the following documents:

- Heart Rate Service (HRS)
- GATT Specification Supplement (GSS)

Both located at: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/

If it did that then it could use the UUIDs in [16-bit UUID Numbers Document](https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf) and work with code examples that exist such as https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/demos/heart-rate-sensor/

Comment: I was just sending dummy data in the Heart rate widget from esp32 to check if data was showing on the app or not, I will set the right number from the sensor afterward

Comment: And also could you please elaborate on why are you asking to use a 16-bit UUID number?

Comment: Using the adopted 16-bit UUID for SERVICE_UUID and CHARACTERISTIC_UUID would indicate you have structured the BLE Heart Rate data in the way defined in the standard. This is totally optional as you are writing the code for both ends of the Bluetooth connection. I was bringing to your attention that these standards existed for how to share heart rate data over Bluetooth and that you could leverage them to reduce the amount of code you needed to write. Apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

If that's really the data format you are receiving and just want to format it differently, try some string manipulation, e.g:

```
final currentValue = '[33]';
  
print(currentValue.substring(1, currentValue.length-1)); // 33
```